# Bitmap is empty when api runs as service

Tags: c#, .net-core, bitmap, xps

When i run the following method when my API is running as a service it generates the bitmaps with the content of the XPS file that i use just fine. But when i run this same method when my API is running as a service with administrator then it generates empty bitmaps.

```cs
public static void ConvertXpsToImg(string xpsFile, string printerName)
        {
            using (var xpsConverter = new Xps2Image(xpsFile))
            {
                var images = xpsConverter.ToBitmap(new Parameters
                {
                    ImageType = ImageType.Png,
                    Dpi = 203
                });

                foreach (Bitmap bitmap in images)
                {
                    using (var pd = new PrintDocument())
                    {
                        pd.PrintPage += (_, e) =>
                        {
                            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0));
                        };
                        pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerName;
                        pd.DefaultPageSettings = new PageSettings(pd.PrinterSettings)
                        {
                            Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0)
                        };
                        pd.Print();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The library i use to make bitmaps from XPS is called Xps2Image but this library is not .net core. But because it runs just fine as console i assume this isn't a problem.

Is there any way to convert XPS to a Bitmap like i do here but for .net core? or could the bitmaps not being loaded as a service have to do with something else?

Comment: It looks like you're converting to an image in order to print it. Is there any reason you can't  print the XPS directly? There should be some APIs which take XPS as the print format.

Comment: The reason that i dont print XPS is because our printers cant print certain lines that are on the document when i use XPS

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I know there are some tools that will render XPS, but the ones I know of are paid solutions.